# How can I count the number of records with @DbColumn?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

I am trying to get a column value for some computed text fields on a page using `@DbColumn`.

Say I have a view called "By Status", like so:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Count | Status |  Created  |  Author  |  Comments  |
+-------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+
|  134  |  Open  |           |          |            |
+-------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+
|       |        | Records with "Status" = "Open"... |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+
|  101  |  Hold  |           |          |            |
+-------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+
|       |        | Records with "Status" = "Hold"... |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+
...
```

Pretty self explanatory - it displays all of the records for the database by status and has a count (number of records) for each status.

On my page I have a computed text field for each of the statuses; Open, Hold, etc. I am trying to get the count by status. So for example:

```
@Text( @DbColumn(  "Notes" : "ReCache" ; "" : "" ; "By Status"; 1 ) );
```

This returns 134, which is the count for the status "Open". I know this is correct for my above statement, however, it's not what I'm going for.

How can I get the value of "Count" for each "Status"? Using `@DbLookup` perhaps..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different ways of doing, what you want to do.
First would be to do a @DbLookup for every value of your status. That would look like this (example for status Open):

```
@DbLookup( "":"ReCache"; ""; "By Status"; "Open"; 1)
```

Depending on the number of status that might become slow.

The other way would be to do a dbcolumn in a computed field (that would mean to take a form for that purpose instead of a page, but that is not really an issue):

Field named "allTotals", number, computed for display, allow multiple values, formula:

```
@DbColumn( "":"ReCache"; ""; "By Status"; 1)
```

And then in each value for the total for a special status you would need its position in the view. First Status:

```
@Subset( @Subset( allTotals; 1 ) ; -1 )
```

Second status:

```
@Subset( @Subset( allTotals; 2 ) ; -1 )
```

...

And of course, there might be other, more complex ways of handling this...

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought about using a `@Subset`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@DbLookup is one solution.  You would want to setup a new view where the Status column is the first column in the view and is sorted alphabetically.  The second column would be the count, and then your formula to get the count that are on Hold would be:

```
@DbLookup("Notes":"NoCache"; "":""; "NewView"; "Hold"; 2);
```

You should also be able to use @DbColumn to get two lists that are related.

```
Statuses := @DbColumn(  "Notes" : "ReCache" ; "" : "" ; "By Status"; 2 );
Counts := @DbColumn(  "Notes" : "ReCache" ; "" : "" ; "By Status"; 1 );
NumberOnHold := @Select(@Member("Hold"; Statuses); Counts);
```

Comment: Could I put `Statuses` and `Counts` in the page `Queryopen`? Then I would only have to reference the last line for each field...

Comment: You might put some hidden computed fields at the top of your form so you can reference them in other fields on your form.  I forget if making them Computed for Display would allow you to reference them but not save them -- worth a shot.

Comment: Ah the old "hidden computed field at the top of the form" trick. Thanks!